# How can I change the view in a container view (embedded view controller)?

Tags: swift, embed, containers, viewcontroller

So I have been trying to do this for a a while, that I need to to do is be able to change the image view that a container view embeds. Is this possible?

I wasn't sure if it was, so I thought that maybe I could just make an embedded view for all of the different views and have them all on top of each other - then just bring the one that the user has chosen to the view to the top.

I'm pretty sure the second way would work, but it would probably slow down the app and isn't very tidy.

I would prefer to use the first way and just be able to choose which view controller the view controller embeds.

I know that stack overflow likes to see that the OP has made an attempt at solving the problem, but I am asking more here if it is possible to do the first way - if it is, how would I go about doing it. If it isn't would my second option be feasible?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post an example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score -2):

One way is as shown below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var imgNumber = 0
var images = ["image0","image1","image2"]
@IBAction func btn(sender: UIButton) {
    imgNumber += 1
    if (imgNumber > 2) {
        imgNumber = 0
    }
    imageToBeDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: images[imgNumber])
}
@IBOutlet weak var imageToBeDisplayed: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageToBeDisplayed.image = UIImage(named: images[0])
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. This is for UIImageView not container views.